# Installing Android Studio in a Computer Lab Environment with Individual Student Logins on OSX

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, configuration, multiple-users

I installed of Android Studio on the main administrator account, including downloading all the appropriate sdks, tools, etc. using the sdk manager, and further installing genymotion.  After everything was set, that computer was imaged and deployed to 36 computers in the lab.  Everything works when logged in as main administrator, but apparently Android Studio likes to keep things in the user's personal library, so no other users' environments are setup appropriately.

I tried copying the Android folder from /Users/main/Library over to the /Users/main/Shared folder, but I can't seem to avoid having to go through the setup wizard and download the latest API (which I don't want for the course).

The way the lab works is we have network accounts for each student.  Any student can go to any computer and login as a standard user with limited access to some system preferences.  If a student were to switch computers (which I do want them to do as they should be working with different partners throughout the year), I don't want them to have to redownload all the sdk tools for the two APIs we'll be using (19 & 21).

The reason why just logging everyone in as main administrator is not an ideal solution is students will not have access to their network drives containing their personal file storage.

Is there any way to setup Android Studio for multiple user accounts, some of which have admin privileges, others having standard user privileges?  The lab contains 36 2013 iMacs running Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Were you able to figure out a solution?

I am dealing with the same scenario, however I'm not re-imaging my lab, just installing the software + Yosemite updates on an existing 10.9 lab.

What I've found that works, is placing the sdk folder into the user template (/System/User Templates/English.proj/Library/Android). This would cause each account to be ~2.5GB though, so not a very practical solution if you have 160Gb disks like me.

What I ended up doing was creating smart links into the user template. By storing the sdk once on the disk (Like /Android/sdk for example), and making a link into each user's profile, the Android Studio launches and works as expected and doesn't eat up precious disk space for every user.

Here is the script I used with Apple Remote Desktop, this includes grabbing the android studio application and sdk from a network share.

```
mkdir /Volumes/fs2/
echo "Mounting share"

mount_smbfs //user:pass@fs2/installs/ /Volumes/fs2/

echo "Copying Android studio Application"
cp -r /Volumes/fs2/software/MacOS/Android/Android\ Studio.app /Applications/
chmod -R 655 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
chown -R root:wheel /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

mkdir /Android

echo "Copying Android sdk folders"
cp -r /Volumes/fs2/software/MacOS/Android/sdk /Android/

chmod -R 655 /Android/
chown -R root:wheel /Android/

umount /Volumes/fs2

echo "Linking sdk to user accounts"
for USER_TEMPLATE in "/System/Library/User Template"/*
do
    ln -s /Android $USER_TEMPLATE/Library/Android
done

for USER_HOME in /Users/*
do
  USER_UID=`basename "${USER_HOME}"`
  if [ ! "${USER_UID}" = "Shared" ]
  then
    ln -s /Android $USER_HOME/Library/Android
  fi
done
```